# WooSquare Syncing & Duplicate SKUs

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, square

We are experiencing issues with products displayed in Square POS Library after syncing our WooCommerce website to Square using the WooSquare plugin. Note that we have 2 locations, one location we are auto-syncing between Square and Woocommerce and the other brick and mortar location we are not syncing. We added a -1 to all of the SKUs for the products of the unsynced location to prevent duplicates. We have made updates in WooCommerce to our Variable Products and have updated Attributes on our products in WooCommerce but changes are not being properly synced to the Square POS. We are also experiencing Duplicate Products. [image] On some of our Variable Products, we cannot read the variations at the POS and cannot select correct variations to ring up the right variations of the products. 
[image]
Could the duplicate product issue come from the fact that we need to add SKUs to the parent of the variable product? We only have SKUs assigned to the variables.

We noticed here https://apiexperts.io/documentation/faq/synchronize-global-attribute-square-woocommerce-variable-products-auto-sync/ it said Note: Make sure before you sync Global attribute from Square to WooCommerce, Add Global attribute in WooCommerce otherwise it will consider as a custom attribute. Also Note: If you have more than 500 products then don’t choose Auto sync hourly. We noticed this after the fact. Note we have around 800 products.

Why can we not sync hourly if we have over 500 products? We changed all products custom attributes to Global attributes? How do we get Square to change the custom attributes to Global attributes or how do we get these corrections to reflect on the square side? Regarding the last question, we think that this issue can be resolved by simply pressing the “Synchronize Woo to Square” Button in WooSquare, but when I press it the dialog box does not fully load even after waiting 5 minutes.
[image]

Can anyone provide any insight on how I can resolve these issues?
Here are some resources for context:
https://apiexperts.io/documentation/topics/woosquare-pro/
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-square/#section-10

Comment: Probably not much use to you now but I also had an issue with WooSquare.  I have posted the resolution of my issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087430/woocommerce-woosquare-plus-plugin-plus-product-variations-must-be-an-array/60087431#60087431.  That information may provide assistance to yourself to resolve your issues or, anyone else interested in the use of the WooSquare Plus plugin - I assume that is the version that you are using (documentation link points to WooSquare Pro)? I also experienced the product sync hanging but that was because I had not set up the App in Square.